# Microsoft bot V4 Skill Bot responds with 500(Internal error) when replied to Root bot at SendActivityAsync function

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying Master and Skill bot functionality by calling Microsoft Sample EchoSkillBot from Master Bot developed by me. Call reached Skill bot from Master but while Skill bot replying to Master getting the exception "InternalServerError". Additional note I'm using LUIS to route the conversations to respective Skill and QnA.

Code: (Exception thrown at this code)

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
           MessageFactory.Text(messageText, 
                               messageText, 
                               InputHints.IgnoringInput), 
           cancellationToken);
```

Error:

> "{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"An error occured while processing your request.","status":500,"traceId":"XXXXX"}"

> "Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'"

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause for the exception. In startup.cs I had used Bot framework adapter as
IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter in one place and other place BotFrameworkHttpAdapter. After fixing this Skill reply worked fine.

```
   // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
   //services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
     services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
     services.AddSingleton<BotAdapter>(sp => sp.GetService<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter>());  //Added for Skill bot
```

Comment: I weirdly made the exact same mistake... The example project showed `services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();` but it felt wrong to not use the interface, so I switched it. :D Oddly it worked fine locally, but when I would deploy the code I would get the 500. I wish the 500 was a little more explanatory, but oh well. Thanks!